# Why does this multiplication of a formal series correspond to an index shift?(from Aigner, A Course in Enumeration, p.55)

Tags: combinatorics, power-series

[image]

I need help understanding the formula. When I plug in numbers in the indices, it makes no sense. Could someone help or guide me to some good introductory material?

Comment: Well...this seems to be missing information. Are we meant to imagine that $a_k=0$ if $k<0$?

Comment: I think the last sum should have been over $n \geq m$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author adopted the convention that $a_k = 0$ for $k  < 0$. Quote from p. 53:

> 2.1  Algebra of Formal Series
> If $A(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n z^n$, then $a_n$ is the $n$-th coefficient of $A(z)$, for which we also write $a_n = [z^n]A(z)$.  Sometimes it is useful to consider coefficients with negative index, with the understanding that $a_k = 0$ for $k<
> 0$.